# Migrating Activiti from 5.22 to 6.0 results in error

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

In order to migrate from Activiti 5.2 to 6.0 we followed
[Migration guide](https://www.activiti.org/migration.html%20).
We using Spring Boot in version 1.5.10.RELEASE. 
This is our activiti process engine configuration:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration springProcessEngineConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
        SpringAsyncExecutor springAsyncExecutor) throws IOException {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration springProcessEngineConfiguration = baseSpringProcessEngineConfiguration(dataSource,
            transactionManager, springAsyncExecutor);
    springProcessEngineConfiguration.setActiviti5CompatibilityEnabled(true);

    springProcessEngineConfiguration.setActiviti5CompatibilityHandler(new DefaultActiviti5SpringCompatibilityHandler());

    return springProcessEngineConfiguration;

}
```

After deploying our application with upgraded activiti version and executing some service tasks(which belong to processes deployed in previous activiti version) we encountered problem as below:

> Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't execute
>   activity :
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntityImpl
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.activiti5.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntity
>     at
>   org.activiti5.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskDelegateExpressionActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskDelegateExpressionActivityBehavior.java:124)
>     at org.activiti5.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:62)
>     ... 772 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: org.activiti5.engine.ActivitiActivityExecutionException: couldn't
>   execute activity :
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntityImpl
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.activiti5.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntity
>     at
>   org.activiti5.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:68)
>     at
>   org.activiti5.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:100)

Any clues are very welcome - thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever discover why this is happening? I'm also experiencing this issue.

Comment: @varcharmander unfortunately we didn't manage to discover solution for this issue :/